# ValueError: could not convert string to float: TF_008_2s

Tags: python, csv

I'm very confused here. I have a code to read a csv file with 2 columns. Here is a piece of data:

```
1,TF_001_2s
2,TF_002_2s
3,TF_003_2s
4,TF_004_2s
5,TF_005_2s
6,TF_006_2s
7,TF_007_1s
8,TF_008_2s
9,TF_009_2s
10,TF_010_1s
```

What I want to do is to replace the number of the first column for the name of the second column in a vector. Here is my function:

```
def rename_flights(self):
    index_flight = self.Names.index("Flight ID")
    with open('Flight_names.csv','rb') as typical_flights:          
        typical_flights_read = csv.reader(typical_flights,delimiter=',')            
        for i in range(len(self.matrix[index_flight])):
            flight_id = int(self.matrix[index_flight][i])               
            for new_typical_flights in typical_flights_read:        
                if flight_id == int(new_typical_flights[0]):
                    self.matrix[index_flight][i] = new_typical_flights[1]
```

This function takes the index of a vector (Names) and uses it in a matrix. This matrix may contain int numbers, and these numbers are those which I want to replace for the string of the csv file. I don't know if I have been enough clear. The problem is in the last line, when I assign the string to the correct position in the matrix. It throws me:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: TF_008_2s
```

I don't know what could be the fail, because I'm not converting any string to float. I hope you all can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Editing-#1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_server.py", line 566, in <module>
    reading(name)
  File "script_server.py", line 552, in reading
    info.rename_flights()
  File "script_server.py", line 272, in rename_flights
    self.results_matrix_rounded[index_flight][i] = new_typical_flights[1]   
ValueError: could not convert string to float: TF_008_2s
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of your exception? Note that you cannot loop over the `typical_flights_read` `csv.reader()` more than once without rewinding the file. Typically, if you are repeating a loop over a file, consider reading the contents into a memory instead.

Comment: Do you store anything in the nested `self.matrix[..]` lists that might implement a `__setitem__` method that tries to call `float()` on the value you are setting?

Comment: What does `type(self.results_matrix_rounded[index_flight])` tell you is stored in the matrix rows? It is that object that expects to convert your string to a float.

Comment: The matrix had float values (I convert to int values in "flight_id = int(self.matrix[index_flight][i])") and I want to replace these values for the strings. Could be this the error? Have I to convert previouly to the assignation to string? How can I convert to string if I have already float values?

Comment: No, the *object type* you used in `self.matrix[index_flight]` is not a standard Python `list` object. It is something that automatically calls `float()` on any value you try to store in it. What is that object type?

Comment: David, you're not using numpy arrays by any chance?

Comment: type(self.results_matrix_rounded[index_flight]) tells me <type 'numpy.ndarray'>.

Comment: @DavidRguez: Right, you have a `numpy` array, which can only hold certain types; this one is configured to only store floats. If you want to store mixed types, don't use a numpy array.

Comment: @DavidRguez You will receive more help if you post the expected output and the Names matrix.

Comment: Oh godness, this is a serious problem for me, because I had all configured to work with numpy array. By the way, thank you all for the help, at least I have localized the error.